# Fitting a gam model with simple Gaussian/Student-t heteroskedasticity

Tags: r, regression, generalized-additive-model

I am fitting a gam model in R (using the `gam` function in `mgcv`) to account for some non-linear effects in my data. A stripped down example of what I am doing in R is:

```
mod=gam(y~s(x)+s(z),data=df)
```

However, I want to add a slightly more complicated variance model to my regression of the form

$$\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2),\ \sigma = f(\hat{\mu})$$

where $\hat{\mu}$ is the fitted value of the model. (Actually, it would be nice if $\epsilon \sim t_\nu$ for some $\nu$ but sticking to this for now. I have managed to do this in the `gls` function from `nlme` using the `varFunc(form=fitted(.))` type approach, but can't figure out if there is an option to do the same kind of thing using `gam`.

I recognise this is not really the intention of a GLM/GAM model, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if I am just missing something obvious

Edit: In response to the question in the comment below, I am hoping to fit a linear or quadratic function for $f$. I do not know the exact form of $f$ but plan to iteratively estimate it from the residuals if this can't be done automatically.

Edit2: Typo in R code - first spline is not meant to be a function of y!

Comment: Do you know the functional form of $f$?

Comment: Well.. I don't know for sure, but I was planning on fitting either a linear or quadratic function of the fitted values.

Comment: Is your target variable $y > 0$ or perhaps $\geq 0$?  If so, that opens up some options...

Comment: Hmm, no unfortunately not. Out of curiosity, what would those options be?

Comment: The "family" parameter in `gam` specifies a link function, as with a generalized linear model; part of that is a specification of a mean-variance relationship.  For example, for the Poisson family, variance = mean (with the default link function); for the Gamma, the standard deviation = the mean (with the default link function.)  You may still be able to make use of this approach by transforming `y` mildly; the nonparametric nature of the right hand side (at least in your example) means you don't have to worry (much) about functional forms being changed by doing so.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That does sound awfully fiddly though, and I feel like I might be better off manually calculating regression weights and iterating.

Comment: Yes, that's another idea.  It's just that if you can do it easily with the "family" parameter, the iteration is handled for you.  But if it's going to be work, it might well be better to do it all by hand, well inside a loop at any rate, and get more flexibility.

Comment: I will have a play around with the 'family parameter' and see if I can get it to work easily for me, but I'm comfortable programming, so it might be easier to get the flexibility like you say. Thanks for the help.